# Why external sorter works in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I made processing data code in scala&spark and somehow it's so slow. I guess it's because of 'ExternalSort'. As you can see my code below, There is no reason to sort data but spark did.

I have more than 6,000,000 rows in RDD and try to cluster data with column name 'ID' (which are less than 20 types, so each ID group would be more than 300,000 rows)

I know It's pretty large data but other process were not slow. Any idea of this?

```
val ListByID = allData.map { x => (x.getAs[String]("ID"), List(x)) }.reduceByKey { (a: List[Row], b: List[Row]) => List(a, b).flatten }

val goalData = ListByID.map({ rowList =>
  val list = rowList._2
  val ID = rowList._1
  val SD = list.head.getAs[String]("SD")

  val ANOTEHR_ID_CNT = list.map{ row=> row.getAs[String]("ANOTHER_ID")}.distinct.length

  Row(
    ID, ID, list.length,
    list.count { row => row.getAs[Int]("FLAGA")==1 },
    list.count { row => row.getAs[Int]("FLAGB")==1 },
    SD, ANOTEHR_ID_CNT)
})
```

Comment: It's not even completed. It stopped with 'jvm heap' error

Comment: " There is no reason to sort data but spark did." Why do you think Spark sorted the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following part:

```
allData.map{...}.reduceByKey{ (a: List[Row], b: List[Row]) => List(a, b).flatten }
```

is just a significantly more expensive implementation of `groupByKey`. It not only puts more pressure on GC by applying map-side aggregations but may also create huge number of temporary objects. If single group doesn't fit into memory then out-of-memory error is inevitable.

Next you group data and drag all the fields when all you do later is counting. It could be easily handled with simple aggregation.

1. Reduce by `ID` and `ANOTHER_ID` counting `FLAGA=1`, `FLAGB=1`  and keeping single `SD`
2. Reduce 1. by `ID`, sum `FLAGA=1`, `FLAGB=1`, `1` (distinct `ANOTHER_ID`), keep arbitrary `SD`.

Finally if you start with `DataFrame` why move data to less efficient format at all? With pseudocode:

```
df.groupBy("ID").agg(
  count($"*"),
  count(when($"FLAGA" === 1, 1)),
  count(when($"FLAGB" === 1, 1))
  countDistinct("ANOTHER_ID"),
  first("SD")
)
```